# How do I put the starting points of the X and Y axes together，with xlim and ylim setting autoscaling?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I put the starting points of the X and Y axes together? Xlim and ylim are set autoscaling, for example using ax.set_xlim(auto=True). The picture shows the style type that I want.

Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Meaning in this case you want the x min to be -1 instead of 1?

Comment: No, not that. If I set auto scaling, the starting points of X-axis and Y-axis are separate. I just want them to coincide, like picture above. Sorry I'm new and I don't know how to post pictures in comments.

Comment: It is not clear what "coincide" means here.  Some possible interpretations are "xmin and ymin must always have the same numeric value," or "the first xtick and the first ytick must always be aligned with the bottom left of the chart."  You'll need to describe more clearly what you're after.

Comment: Sorry that I'm not clear. I mean  "the first xtick and the first ytick must always be aligned with the bottom left of the chart.", with xlim and ylim setting autoscaling

Comment: It isn't even clear if the picture shows the case you have and that you want to change, or if the picture shows the case you want to have. You may need to read [ask] again. Then [edit] your question accordingly. In this case I could imagine that you want to show us a [mcve] of a code that does not produce what you want, then explain in how far it does not meet the requirements and then ask how to change it, such that it meets the requirement.

Comment: Maybe you want to read [ask] yet another time? The only thing I understand from the question is that you set a parameter to "automatic" which, in reality, you don't want to be automatic at all. The solution is simple: don't set it to automatic. However, this leaves the *actual*  problem unsolved. Hence you need to tell us what the *actual*  problem *is*.

Comment: This is what the problem is and you got the point. If I set the xlim and ylim a certain value I will get the style I want. Now the problem is, how can I get the same style when I set xmin and ylim auto scaling?I wonder whether any parameters adjustment in matplotlib can work？Thank you.

Comment: You asked this same question earlier today and then deleted it when I pointed out the same thing as @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Deleting a re-asking a bad question isn't appropriate.

Comment: In that question I did't express clearly so I delete it. I did not deliberately delete the question because of your comment

Comment: The correct thing to do for an unclear question is to edit the question to make it better. The above question is in need of editing. Add to the question a short example of code that creates the graph with the wrong appearance so that someone else can reproduce the "problem". Then explain clearly what you are trying to achieve and you are very likely to get a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for you help. No matter whether the problem is solved or not, I should read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) again more carefully. It's a big mistake asking unclear questions.

Comment: @Craig Deleting a question when understanding that it is not suitable to be asked here, is perfectly fine. However, it should be clear that when then asking a new question, the new question should actually improve and comply with [ask]. It should also be clear that iterating this (deleting and asking new questions over several cycles) would be a misuse of SO.

Comment: @Joe To summarize: The question is still unclear and not according to [ask]. If the answer you found solves the `actual` problem you have, it's good for you, but the complete post is useless for everyone else. I would therefore recommend to either delete this question as well, or to finally edit it to show an actual problem for which the answer below would be a solution.

Answer (score -1):

I searched the docs and found [`Axes.autoscale`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale.html?highlight=autoscale#matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale). Set `ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=True)` and it works

Comment: You apparently found a solution to a problem which is not clear from the question. It is thus useless for others. (The little I do understand from the question is that there should be ticks at the plot's edges, which `autoscale` [does not guarantee at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9Eqb.png)).

Comment: I edited my answer that `enable=True` should be added. Too tired that I made several mistakes.

Comment: `enable=True` is the default. Even if you don't explicitely use it, the result stays the same.

Comment: Oh That's so weird, but it works fine for me. I'm going to ask my friend when he's online. I can hardly describe the question clearly, what a shame.

Comment: As long as "*it*" is not well defined, nothing is weird. The reason you are unable to ask a clear question is that you ignore [ask]. This article gives you a clear guideline to follow when asking a question. If you stick to that guideline, your question will be understandable. If you ignore it, you shoudn't wonder about anything.

Comment: I got that. Thanks anyway.